# Is it possible to reconduct "The delayed quantum eraser experiment" in home?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-eraser

The delayed quantum eraser was conducted by Kim et al. in 1999 with the use of BBO crystals, polarizers, detectors and so on. I believe some of these equipments can be found online kinda cheaply, except the BBO crystal. I know that the crystal was mainly used for the production of entangled photons, so is there any way to similarly produce entangled photons in low facilities and conduct a similar experiment to get similar results?

Comment: can you put a price tag on 'kinda cheaply'? It seem you can get BBO crystals from 360€ onwards:http://eksmaoptics.com/nonlinear-and-laser-crystals/nonlinear-crystals/beta-barium-borate-bbo-crystals/ I might be wrong, but shoudnt the laser and detector system be more expensive?

Comment: You're definitely right, but the thing in my mind was if I find another way to produce quantum entanglement, I will not need to stick with the laser requirements of the BBO crystal, so I was thinking that I could use an ordinary laser, or in more general a light source. For the detectors, I was thinking have screens in order to directly demonstrate the dual nature of light.

Comment: Isnt the downconversion rate like 10^-6? (I guess you looked that up already). I always thought you need either high intensity laser or highly sensitive detectors.

Comment: If I use a BBO crystal, possibly yes, I guess it also changes with the properties of the crystal. However, in the case of directly observing the effect on a dark screen, I was thinking that any common laser source might help me with the demonstration. The main reason I was interested in the demonstration rather than the experimental data and their graphical interpretation is that I was given to introduce a project which was mainly dedicated to creating an understanding of modern and quantum physics.

Comment: I dont think there are currently other possibilities (except other crystals with the same problem) to create entanglement; which you need if you want a delayed QE, isnt it?

Comment: Yeah, I performed a much more detailed literature search and came up with the fact that there are easily-doable entanglement methods. Thank you so much for your help @lalala .